# How to get php documentation in sublime codeintel

Tags: sublimetext, sublimecodeintel

I use Sublime Text 3 & its CodeIntel plugin for my basic PHP development and I need it to show me a documentation of a function(either built-in function or from a 3rd party class) whenever I ctrl+shift+space over the function.

How do I go about this?

Comment: You'll need another plugin - SublimeCodeIntel is not for documentation.

Comment: what plugin would that be, that will display docblock documentations of methods for me?